# Make app generated content show in stock android Downloads app

Tags: android

We are working on an android app that generates PDFs based on app contents on users' request. We are providing an option to launch an email agent and attach the generate PDF, but we also want the user be able to view the document later at any time. On android, there are no stock file explorer, so our first thought was to show on the stock Downloads app's file list. We've tried the following two methods but without luck.

We firstly tried to save the PDF to the default download folder (given by calling `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)`) and invoke media scanner, but the file doesn't show up in the Downloads app's list. It's shown in Adobe Acrobat's local document list though.

After some research, it seems that the Downloads app would only show files that downloaded though `DownloadManager`, so we tried to generate the PDF in a temporary directory and call DownloadManager to download it, but, somehow expected, it complains that we can only download via HTTP(S), so this approach isn't working as well.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you have to provide access to the document without any file explorer app, i think your approach is correct it to allow to store it in the Download lists. To achive this you can use [Nanohttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) in your application to host your pdf document and then invoke the DownloadManager download action using HTTP(S) to your webapp (you will have to create a small webapp to handle the download request) hosted on localhost server.

Comment: Haha, thought about this approach, but hesitated. It sounds like nothing but an overkill to me, but maybe it's the only valid solution.